# Why don't we use "the" in this sentence structure? (sometimes)

Tags: grammar, articles

How come in English, we have this structure that omits "the".

> The school is in need of funding.
>
> He is in search of adventure.
>
> ***Subject*** + is in + ***X*** + of +  ***Y***

But then, also have "the"

> We are in need of a guitarist.
>
> They are in search of the truth.

If we need to be specific and had to use "the" only in specific cases, that would be okay. But "a guitarist" is a general term, why not "a funding", for example? Is this a special case? Are there any specific words that don't require "the"/"a"?

Comment: "Count" vs "non-count" nouns.

Comment: In point of fact, in the right contexts, both the definite and indefinite article could be used in each of your initial sentences.

Comment: In English, singular count nouns always need an article – either the definite or the indefinite one. Uncountable nouns and plural nouns, on the other hand, only take an article when the NP is used in a specific, definite sense – and then it's always the definite article that's used. I may develop this into a proper answer if I can find the time, but this'll have to do for now; it's an interesting question anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hannah! If you do decide to develop it into an answer, I'd happily mark it as correct.